# Push data to MySQL CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to insert data to `MySQL`. I'm facing few issues while inserting data.
I have tried following stuff:

Controller (new1):

```
public function new1()
{
    $this->load->view('example1');
}
```

View (example1) :

```
<?php $num=0;
$id=0;
for($a=0;$a<10;$a++)
{
    $num[$a]=$a;
    $id[$a]=$a+1000;
}


?>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('controller/new'); ?>">insert data</a>
```

Controller (new) :

```
public function new()
{

    $datas = array
    (
    'id'=>$this->input->post('id'),
    'num'=>$this->input->post('num'),
    );
    $return=$this->model->example($datas);
    if($return == true) {
    $data['result_msg'] = 'Json data successfully inserted into database !';
    } else {
    $data['result_msg'] = 'Please configure your database correctly';
    }

    $this->load->view('success',$data);
}
```

Model (examples)

```
public function examples($datas) 
    {
    $this->db->insert('test1', $datas);
    if ($this->db->affected_rows() > 0) 
    {
    return true;
    } else 
    {
    return false;
    }
    }
```

view (success)

```
<?php
echo $result_msg;
?>
```

Comment: What is your exact Problem and what type of data is «num»? On the first look, your code seams to be okay.

Comment: it's integer
I want to insert 1 - 10 to my database table
but I'm getting 0 and 0 for my database

Comment: Please switch on db debug and show the error message. To switch debug on, set db_debug in application/config/database.php to TRUE and reload your page and for debugging your PHP stuff it is a good idea to enable error reporting. This is done in the index.php, sitting in htdocs.

Comment: I solved it, by using normal php
so I load the connection in my view
then directly push the array into my database
thanks mr. Joerg

Comment: Great, that it works but it is not a good way to do it. The main purpose of Codeigniter is, that you structure your PHP project. If you don't use the structure of Codeigniter, you don't need it. So, use the view, just for the output of your data, the model for the database things and the controller for interpreting and manipulation of the data. The other purpose of codeigniter is to protect you in writing unsecure PHP oder SQL code.

Comment: You are not passing your data to controller. Please check if you get any data in `function new`. By printing `post`.

Comment: @Joerg yeah, I need to learn more, I'm really new to codeigniter, it got me confused with all the variable passing and stuff

Comment: @Nitin I don't know how to pass the variable to controller, it doesn't print anything, just blank page, would you tell me how to do it?
thanks

Comment: You can post data using the form submission and post method. Second way is using ajax.

Comment: the data I'll be using is in json from another website, so using submission form or post method is out, it leaves me with ajax then
I never use ajax before, I'll read about ajax then
thanks Nitin :D